# CSS How to put a border around the entire nav bar

Tags: css

https://jsfiddle.net/gnpoy2jc/

I would like to make a border around the entire nav element. Not each individual a tag. I can't seem to get it to work

HTML

```
<nav class="bigBar">
                    <a class="about"  href="#">ABOUT</a>
                    <a class="ministries" href="#">MINISTRIES</a>
                    <a class="evangelsts" href="#">EVANGELSTS</a>
                    <a class="resources" href="#">RESOURCES</a>
            </nav><!--end class bigBar-->
```

CSS

```
.bigBar a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
  background: #933737; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, you can modify both width values to adjust it yo your page

```
.bigBar{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}
.bigBar a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
  background: #933737; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a border to the container element so in your case `.bigBar`. Since your child elements are `float: left;` You'll need to apply a clearfix. Therefore add this to your css:

```
.bigBar{
  border: 10px solid black;
}

.bigBar:after{
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are putting the border around every `<a>` element. Remove the 'a' in your CSS and it should work.

```
.bigBar {
    border:1px solid;
}
```

Well, I see you didn't specify a border so also add `border:1px solid;`